# объединить вторые поля при совпадении первых

Tags: unix, sh

Имеются строки:

```
vmwVmMAC.43      0:50:56:96:5b:63
vmwVmMAC.44      0:50:56:96:4d:20
vmwVmMAC.45      0:50:56:b7:1b:32
vmwVmMAC.45      0:50:56:b7:2b:4b
```

Как их преобразовать к такому виду, объединив вторые поля при совпадении первых полей:

```
vmwVmMAC.43      0:50:56:96:5b:63
vmwVmMAC.44      0:50:56:96:4d:20
vmwVmMAC.45      0:50:56:b7:1b:32 , 0:50:56:b7:2b:4b
```

Требуется инструмент, которому можно передавать исходные строки через «трубу» (pipe):

```
$ cat file | merge --by -f1 -d'\t'
```

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Первый раз вижу, чтоб `pipe` кто-то трубой называл в данном контексте.

Comment: @alexolut, предложите более удачный перевод.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin канал или конвейер, например.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: это было переведно Александром с крайне убогого руглиша :) Я был уверен, что есть способ сделать это одним пайплайном с каким-нибудь sed-ом :) Но и так хорошо работает, для моих задач сойдет, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно это сделать, например, с помощью небольшой программы для интерпретатора *awk*:

```awk
BEGIN {
  OFS="";
}

{ 
  if (NR==1) {
    k="";
  } else {
    if (n==$1) { 
      if (k!="") k=k" , ";
    } else {
      print n,"\t",k;
      k="";
    }
  }
  n=$1;
  $1="";
  k=k$0;
}

END {
  print n,"\t",k;
}
```

вызывать эту программу, сохранив её в файл `программа.awk`, можно так:

```
$ awk -f программа.awk file
```

или так:

```
$ cat file | awk -f программа.awk
```

---

пример работы:

```
$ cat file
1   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
3   e
3   f
$ cat file | awk -f программа.awk 
1   a , b
2   c
3   d , e , f
```